# Where should SCVMM be installed?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, scvmm

We have 2 Hyper-V servers running in a small office, and are looking at using SCVMM for managing VMs. I have used SCVMM before, but only in test environments, and I have always installed it on a VM. In a production environment, where should SCVMM be installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install SCVMM 2008 R2 and 2012 onto a physical server or in a Virtual Machine - fully supported.  The choice is yours.  Just keep in mind that if you lose the Hyper-V host that is hosting the SCVMM VM, you will have to resort to Hyper-V Manager to manage your Hyper-V hosts.

Comment: Thanks! that makes my life easier. I suppose, probably best to keep a replica on both machines with the 2012 replication feature, and if one goes down, stat it on the other... Thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome.  Gotta love the free Hyper-V Replica!!